# RequireJS and scripts that depend on being loaded in a specific order

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am trying to include in this [web application](https://github.com/thomasdavis/backbonetutorials/tree/gh-pages/examples/todo-app) the library jquery-ui.

For this purpose I changed the code in this way:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery-min',
    ui: 'libs/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-min', // ******** I just added this line ********
    underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore-min',
    backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone-optamd3-min',
    text: 'libs/require/text'
  }
});

require(['views/app'], function(AppView){
  var app_view = new AppView;
});
```

Sometimes I get the following error:

```
jQuery is not defined
```

Since RequireJS loads and evaluates scripts in an undetermined order,
I suppose it depends by the fact that `jquery.ui` library (which depends from `jquery`), sometimes is loaded before jquery.

According the [documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#order) I can use the `order plugin`.
Anyway for backbone which requires underscore this issue never happens.

So my questions are:

Why for backbone (which depend by underscore) this issue never happens ?

I have to use the `order plugin` to fix my problem for `jquery-ui`?

Comment: For your final question: jQuery UI depends on jQuery and therefore requires jQuery to be loaded before it.

Comment: I'm running into this issue right now, with a jQuery+jQuery-UI+underscore+request web app. Did you find the solution?

Comment: good question! why would something like this happen?

Answer (score 2):

Backbone *does* need the `order` or some other plugin to load in order too...

Except in your case you have already made the choice to not use the normal Backbone but rather a fork from James Burke (I guess from here: https://github.com/jrburke/backbone). This is indicated by you specifying the Backbone path to `backbone-optamd3-min`. Seems you have forgotten about it ;)
Using the amd branch is fine, as long as you remember you made this choice. If you decide to go with a plugin instead you could use the *normal* Backbone.js.